# Why does Spring RestTemplate.getForObject() to localhost get a 404 when a curl to the identical url from the same host works fine?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs

I have a SpringBoot service that usually makes a call to an external REST service.  It is generally working fine.  The external service is Bing Maps, but that is not important.

I need to do some temporary mocking of the result provided by this external service, so I've generated a small SpringBoot Jersey skeleton app and gave a single resource method the same Path value as the service being called.  I run it in Eclipse and set a breakpoint in that method. I started this mock service on port 8090.

In the main service, I also run it in Eclipose and set a breakpoint at the point where it's about to call Bing Maps.  I saved the full url it connects to.  From a shell, I used "curl" to connect to that url, changing the host:port to "localhost:8090", so that it goes to the mock service instead of the real Bing Maps service.  It hit the breakpoint in the method in my mock service, and I let it return to the main service, and the result was consistent with what I sent back from the mock service.

I then went back to the breakpoint in the main service and changed the url it was about to connect to to be the exact url that I connected to from "curl".  I let it continue.

The call failed with a 404.  It never hit the breakpoint in the mock service.

I'm at a loss to understand this.  Both the main service and the mock service are running on my laptop, listening on ports 8080 and 8090 respectively.

Why can I reach the mock service url from curl from my shell, but not from the service?

Comment: Never mind, I didn't realize that the service was requiring the use of a proxy, which will not work connecting to a service running on localhost.

Comment: Could you please post how to send using `curl` and `RestTemplate#getForObject(..)`? Looks like you are calling it in different ways...